# RWD-navigation off canvas-pattern: How to scroll the flyout areas — only?

Tags: cross-browser, navigation, cross-platform, responsive-design, smartphone

I´m using awesome Brad Frosts left nav flyout for my responsive design navigation. (http://codepen.io/bradfrost/pen/IEBrz).

I need some advice for the flyout. I need the flyout-area to be scrolled separately, not affecting the main content area — like the facebook app.

My experience so far is pretty bad when it comes to crossover support for fixed, scrollable areas (with complex elements inside) for smartphones combined with relative heights and meaures (the site is responsive). I´ve tried iScroll and jQuery mobile so far.

Would it be possible to accomplish scrolling the flyout ONLY without a huge amount of javascript-plugins, client-sniffing and CSS vendor-specific hacks?

My client really likes the flyout pattern. Performance, crossdevice support and non-hacky code is a "must have". Native look and feel is a "could have". I have no problem recommend another way to solve the navigation, I just need to be sure of my decision. Of course everything can be done — but to what cost?

Do you have any recommendations or advice before I cut the rope :) ?

Answer (score 0):

The preview you've put up is looking really promising!

What I would suggest is that you use a little JavaScript to detect the window height.  You can then set the height of the fly-out panel to the same height as the page and use `display: block;  overflow: auto`.  (It's possible that it already has block-display set).

This will force the panel to scroll within itself rather than flow further.

A few things worth bearing in mind:

- You'll need to recalculate the height on window change or orientation change;
- Touch-screen devices tend not to display scroll bars, this is a double-edged sword because it means you get a really nice app-like feel when you swipe up/down.  However, it also means that users may need a little more of a visual hint that there's something to scroll for!